# Calling Getter Method Repetitively vs Storing Returned Value

Tags: performance

I couldn't find anything regarding this so if I'm asking a question already answered I apologise.

When it comes to programming, in general, would it be better performance-wise to call a getter method a couple of times in the same function to achieve the desired outcome, or should one rather call the getter once and store the value it returned?

For example, if I have this method to do a binary search:

```
   n ← size of the array
   x ← value to be searched

   Set lowerBound = 1
   Set upperBound = n 

   while true
      if upperBound < lowerBound 
         EXIT: x does not exists.
   
      set midPoint = lowerBound + ( upperBound - lowerBound ) / 2
      
      if getArray()[midPoint] < x
         set lowerBound = midPoint + 1
         
      if getArray()[midPoint] > x
         set upperBound = midPoint - 1 

      if getArray()[midPoint] = x 
         EXIT: x found at location midPoint
   end while
```

Or should it rather store the array as follows:

```
   A ← getArray() 
   n ← size of the array
   x ← value to be searched

   Set lowerBound = 1
   Set upperBound = n 

   while true
      if upperBound < lowerBound 
         EXIT: x does not exists.
   
      set midPoint = lowerBound + ( upperBound - lowerBound ) / 2
      
      if A[midPoint] < x
         set lowerBound = midPoint + 1
         
      if A[midPoint] > x
         set upperBound = midPoint - 1 

      if A[midPoint] = x 
         EXIT: x found at location midPoint
   end while
```

Thanks in advance!

[Code Adapted From TotorialsPoint](https://www.tutorialspoint.com/data_structures_algorithms/binary_search_algorithm.htm)

Comment: [This answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/19445786/7389264) to a similar question gives a useful answer: using local variables is probably better for readability. In specific usages and languages, it may also be more performant, especially if the method is computationally expensive.

Comment: [Here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/1923866/) is another useful answer to another similar question. Despite being written specifically about Java, the same ideas broadly apply in general.

Comment: @jirassimok thank you for your comments, both links provide good reasons but your first comment's linked answer was more useful to me. Thanks again.